# Persistent nfs ports

Tags: nfs

How can I make NFS4 `nlockmgr` listen on specified ports only? I've got these two variables defined on my CentOS 7 system in `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` and opened up the usual ports 2049, 111, 2020.

```
LOCKD_TCPPORT=32803
LOCKD_UDPPORT=32769
```

But what's still happening is that I'm getting the random ports like this:

```
    100021    1   udp  51963  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  51963  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  51963  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  51670  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  51670  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  51670  nlockmgr
```

The problem with the random ports is that they won't work with an `iptables` configuration. (Disabling `iptables` allows NFS4 to work, but that's not a useful solution.)

Comment: You've mentioned the correct variables for (at least) a RHEL-based system. What system (distribution) are you running. What have you done with these variable definitions so far? (Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/369477/edit) to include this missing information.)

Comment: @roaima I have added the lock part in `vi /etc/sysconfig/nfs ` it is cent os 7 system with iptables enabled.. I have opened up usual 2049 111 2020 ports on it,, but the `nlockmgr` keeps on changing and I think it creates an issue hence unable to mount nfs , but when iptables disabled it work.fine

Comment: Please put that in the question. Not in the comments.

Comment: @roaima if. U don't want to help it ok ,, but plzz don't bug me like this,, I'm on mobile and it very difficult,, so I really appreciate a sincere help instead of comments like this!!!

Comment: Not bugging. But if you want to maximise your chances of getting an answer (not necessarily from me) it's best to make the information highly visible. Since I'm on a desktop today I'll edit in your comments for you.

Answer (score 0):

Over on ServerFault I've found an almost identical question, [NFS issue Behind iptables in Centos 7](https://serverfault.com/a/726732/267016) that suggests that you need to rebuild a (hidden) configuration file before restarting NFS:

```
systemctl restart nfs-config
```

<sub>(IMO if this is true it's poor programming. This update of a hidden configuration file should be hidden from users and handled automatically.)</sub>